# apt-get doesn't see packages in my trivial repository

Tags: apt, repository

I've tried to set up a trivial repository with binary .debs for internal use, but apt-get doesn't see the packages. I've done the following:

On the web server:

1. Created the binary debs with dpkg-buildpackage
2. Put all of the binary debs in a web-accessible directory which corresponds to  `http://www.example.com/packages`
3. Generated a Packages.gz file in the same directory by doing:

   `dpkg-scansources . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz`

On the client machine:

Added the following line to my /etc/apt/sources.list file:

`deb http://www.example.com/packages /`

Ran: `sudo apt-get update`

The output related to my trivial repository looked like this:

```
Ign http://www.example.com  Release.gpg
Ign http://www.example.com/packages/  Translation-en_US
Ign http://www.example.com  Release
Ign http://www.example.com  Packages
Ign http://www.example.com  Packages
Hit http://www.example.com  Packages
```

But I can't install the package by name. For example, there's a package called "python-nova" which corresponds to package `python-nova_2011.3-custom~bzr680-0ubuntu1_all.deb`

I've tried to do: `apt-get install python-nova`, but I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-nova
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package python-nova
```

Comment: Did you check the contents of Packages.gz on the server ? Does it contain the information for python-nova as expected ?

Comment: can you try with `dpkg-scanpackages` instead of `dpkg-scansources`

Comment: Instead of doing things manually like that, use [a tool for built for the task](http://serverfault.com/questions/224149/debian-apt-get-repository/224635#224635).

Comment: @jet That was it! I was using dpkg-scansources when I should have been using dpkg-scanpackages. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try with `dpkg-scanpackages` instead of `dpkg-scansources`